# Where to find the full information about a signal?

Tags: linux, signals

I want to know the full information about the `SIGTTIN` signal, for example I want to know if the `SIGTTIN` signal can be handled or not.

This [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) only says the following about the `SIGTTIN` signal:

> SIGTTIN   21,21,26    Stop    Terminal input for background process

And typing `man SIGTTIN` in the terminal didn't return anything.

---

**Edit:**

What I meant was not what signals you can send to a process, but rather whether the process that receives the signal can change the signal's default action. For example: the default action for the `SIGTTIN` signal is to stop the process, you can change this default action in your program using the `sigaction()` function. Now some signals don't allow you to change their default actions, and this is what I'm looking for (a documentation of what signals that don't allow you to change their default actions).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command, which is usually correct.

```
kill -l | egrep SIGTTIN
```

You can also write a quick PERL script to trap SIGTTIN + then run it in background + output a simple diagnostic message if your SIGTTIN handler runs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the default action of a signal, any more than ignoring the signal completely, or installing a signal handler. [`sigaction(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) says:

> *sa_handler* specifies the action to be associated with signum and may
>          be `SIG_DFL` for the default action, `SIG_IGN` to ignore this signal, or
>          a pointer to a signal handling function.  This function receives the
>          signal number as its only argument.

If you want to change the action of some signal to one of the other default actions, you could raise another signal that does what you want (to get a core dump or to stop the process), or just plain exit (to terminate the process).

`SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` are the two signals that you can't catch or block. `sigaction(2)`:

> *signum* specifies the signal and can be any valid signal except
>          `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`.

and [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

> The signals `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught, blocked, or
>          ignored.

However, ignoring signals that came from real faults (invalid memory accesses, invalid instructions) might not leave the process in a very stable state.